# Serving static files in nginx using alias

Tags: nginx

I have got the following location specified in nginx:

```
location ~ ^/blah/(.*)$ {
   alias /html/$1;
   autoindex on;
   allow all;
}
```

The `html` directory has the following structure:

```
/html/
   - other/
       - test2.htm
   - test.htm
```

I can browse to `http://server/blah` and get a file listing.

I can serve `http://server/blah/other/test2.htm`.

When I try to access `http://server/blah/test.htm` I get a 301 and a redirect to `http://server/blah/test.htm/` and then a 404.

How can I serve the page at `http://server/blah/test.htm`?

Comment: Show full config

Comment: BTW, why do you use regexp location?

Comment: It was working, but I needed to use chrome in incognito mode as it was caching old failed request responses making it hard to figure out what was going on, hangs head in shame :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably redirect happens somewhere else in the config, adding `break` should help to get what you need:

```
location ~ ^/blah/(.*)$ {
    alias /full/path/to_your/html/dir/$1;
    autoindex on;
    fancyindex on;
    allow all;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried that and it fails to serve anything and doesn't produce a directory listing :-(

Comment: This one tested to work :)